# LibGDX silently fails loading many textures

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I'm using ~100 textures in one game screen, so I thought it would be OK to load them before the actual game starts. Game's create:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false);

    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    Texture.setAssetManager(assetManger());

    Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "textures load started at: " + TimeUtils.nanoTime());

    assetManager.load(cardBackSidePath, Texture.class);
    assetManager.load(backgroundPath, Texture.class);
    for (String texturePath : cards) {
        assetManager.load(texturePath, Texture.class);
    }

    assetManager.finishLoadingAsset(backgroundPath);

    setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
}
```

LoadingScreen is stub screen for now. In render() method I check AssetManager whether all needed textures are loaded and then swap screens:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    if (!PlayScreen.class.equals(getScreen().getClass()) && assetManager.update()) {
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "textures loaded at: " + TimeUtils.nanoTime());
        setScreen(new PlayScreen(this, cardBackSidePath));
    }

    final Texture backgroundTexture = assetManager.get(backgroundPath, Texture.class);

    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);

    super.render();

    batch.end();
}
```

But after some time loading textures it's just silently finished without any log messages provided. Tested on android. Textures are 1024x2048 png so this could be a real issue. But is there any way to get exact error message?

Comment: That's a huge amount of textures. Are you sure you need that many textures at that resolution?

Comment: @manabreak, absolutely unsure. In fact I think that textures will be scaled twice. However there are already 4k display devices, and this resolution would be totally OK for them. But duplicating assets for lower resolutions and for higher ones would enlarge apk size greatly. This is not actual problem, however silent error is problem.

Comment: One 1024x2048 texture takes 8MB of video ram, 11 with mip mapping. Do the math.

Comment: So it is possibly no logs because memory issues. Seems legit.